# TStatusBar with bottom aligned panel

Tags: delphi, alignment, statusbar

I have a form with a `TStatusBar`, and bottom aligned `TPanel`, a bottom aligned `TSplitter` and client aligned `TPanel`, as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: Screen Shot 1 - Before - Good]

(The splitter is coloured red to make it a little more obvious)

Button1 simply increases the height of Panel1 by 20:

```
Panel1.Height := Panel1.Height + 20;
```

But when clicked the order of the controls changes, with Panel1 being blow the status bar and the splitter is now resizing the status bar.

[image: Screen Shot 2 - After - Bad]

This only happens when the height of Panel1 is increased by more than the height of StatusBar1 (19).

I assume this is caused by having two bottom aligned controls, but I'm at a loss as to the exact cause of the problem and how to work around it.

I'm currently using XE2, but I have the same issue with D2010.

In this situation is there a way to set the height of Panel1 to an arbitrary value, while ensuring that the controls maintain their expected positions?

Comment: I was hoping that after fourteen years, Bo… Impr… Code G… Embarcadero would have fixed this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Work around the problem by setting the Top property for the controls after changing the panel height.

```
StatusBar1.Top := Panel1.Top + Panel1.Height;
```

Comment: A cunningly simply solution.  Excellent!  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (worked fine for me):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Panel1.SetBounds(Panel1.Left, Panel1.Top - 20,
                   Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height + 20);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you don't want to keep track of where you're changing position/size of controls,

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  private
  protected
    procedure AlignControls(AControl: TControl; var Rect: TRect); override;

..

procedure TForm1.AlignControls(AControl: TControl; var Rect: TRect);
begin
  inherited;
  if AControl = Panel1 then
    StatusBar1.Top := Panel1.Top + Panel1.Height;
end;
```

Comment: An excellent idea, but I'm only setting the panel height in a single place, so I can go with something simpler.  I'll keep it in mind should things change...